# Javascript add string to start

Tags: javascript, string

my code:

```
var test = "aa";
test += "ee";
alert(test);
```

Prints out "aaee"

How can I do the same thing, **but add the string not to end, but start**:
Like this:

```
var test = "aa";
test = "ee" + test;
```

This is the long way, but is there somekind of **shorter way** like in 1st example?

**What I want is that I must not write the initial variable out again in definition.**

Comment: Your two code samples are not the same. The first yields "aaee" the second "eeaa";

Comment: @Dave thats what I want to do, read the bold :P

Comment: jQuery offers a .prepend() function. In pure JS I would just do test += "ee"; Also, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no built-in operator that allows you to achieve this as in the first example. Also `test = "ee" + test;` seems pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it this way ..

```
test = test.replace (/^/,'ee');
```

*disclaimer: http://xkcd.com/208/*

---

[image: Wait, forgot to escape a space. Wheeeeee[taptaptap]eeeeee.]

Answer (score 1):

You have a few possibilities although not a really short one:

```
var test = "aa";

// all yield eeaa
result = "ee" + test;
result = test.replace(/^/, "ee");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "aa";
 alert('ee'.concat(test));
```

Comment: isn't `test = "ee" + test;` shorter?

Answer (score 0):

What you have, `test = "ee" + test;` seems completely fine, and there's no shorter way to do this.

If you want a `js` solution on this you can do something like,

```
test = test.replace(/^/, "ee");
```

There are a [whole lot of ways](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) you can achieve this, but `test = "ee" + test;` seems the best imo.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **string** at the start (multiple times, if needed) until the resulting string reaches the length you want with [String.prototype.padStart().](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) like this:

```
var test = "aa";
test = test.padStart(4, "e");
alert(test);
```

Prints out

> eeaa

```
var test = "aa";
test = test.padStart(5, "e");
alert(test);
```

Prints out

> eeeaa